# How do I run several linear regressions at once in R?

Tags: r, lm

If I have a dataset with variable A, X, Y, and Z and I want to run two linear regressions - both have A as the dependent variable but one has X as the independent variable and the other has Y (note - NOT multiple regression), what can I do?

`lm(A ~ X, Y, df = df)`  doesn't seem to work, and obviously `lm(A ~ X + Y, df = df)` becomes a multiple regression. I can use `lm(A ~ ., - Z, df = df)` but I'm looking for a way that I could pick and choose multiple variables to use as the independent variable. Thanks.

Comment: try `lm(A ~ X | Y, df`

Answer (score 1):

`lmList` in nlme can run multiple regressions at once:

```
library(nlme)

DF <- data.frame(A = 1:10, X = 1:5, Y = 11:15, Z = 1:10)

DF2 <- cbind(A = DF$A, stack(DF[c("X", "Y")]))
lmList(A ~ values | ind, DF2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using `formulas()` from package `modelr` :

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, X = 1:5, Y = 11:15, Z = 1:10)

library(modelr)

ll <- formulas(~ A,
              m1 = ~ X,
              m2 = ~ Y
)

results_list <- lapply(ll, lm, data = df)
```